# Print Sum of int > 0

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a number S ( int > 0 ) and  n (int > 0), print all the different subsets of len n which sum to S.
For S = 7 and n = 3, the output is the following, the output must be descending order:

```
5 + 1 + 1
4 + 2 + 1 
3 + 3 + 1
3 + 2 + 2
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
vector<vector<int> > partitions(int X, int Y)
{
    vector<vector<int> > v;
    if (X <= 1 && X <= X - Y + 1)
    {
        v.resize(1);
        v[0].push_back(X);

        return v;
    }
    for (int y = min(X - 1, Y); y >= 1; y--)
    {
        vector<vector<int> > w = partitions(X - y, y);
        for (int i = 0; i<w.size(); i++)
        {
            w[i].push_back(y);
            v.push_back(w[i]);
        }
    }
    return v;


}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > v = partitions(7, 3);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x<v[i].size(); x++)
            printf("%d ", v[i][x]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

the first element in the matrix is s- n + 1 and full of 1 till the sum is reached, or if the s-n+1 is equal to s, then n is 1, so only s will be the solution.

p.s.: I don t know if this problem has a particular name

Comment: Do not post links to what you've tried. Post your code here. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok, can you give me a hint, an idea or something ?

Comment: Practically all development environments come with debugging software you can use to control the execution of the program, stepping through it instruction by instruction if you have to, and allow you to inspect its state (see the variables). Fire up the debugger. Step through the program until you see the program something you didn't expect. Congratulations! You found a bug. Now use the variables to figure out why the program did the wrong thing. Start working backwards to figure out how variables got set into values that caused the incorrect behaviour. Rinse. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution for your problem, since it's not a dynamic programming based solution. In this case, I'm using recursion to fill an array until I reduce the desired number to 0. In this solution, every combination will be stored in the increasing order of the elements so we prevent permutations of a already calculated solution.

```
#include <iostream>
void findCombinationGivenSize(int numbersArray[], int index, int num, int reducedNum, int maxNum){
    if (reducedNum < 0)
        return; // this is our base case
    if (reducedNum == 0 && index == maxNum){ // both criteria were attended: 
                                           //the sum is up to num, and the subset contain maxNum numbers
        for (int i = index - 1; i>=0; i--)
            std::cout<< numbersArray[i] << " + ";
        // here we will have a problem with an extra '+' on the end, but you can figure out easily how to remove it :)
        std::cout<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    // Find the previous number stored in arrayNumber[]
    int prev;
    if(index == 0)
        prev = 1;
    else
        prev = numbersArray[index-1];
    for (int k = prev; k <= num; k++){
        // next element of array is k
        numbersArray[index] = k;
        // call recursively with reduced number
        findCombinationGivenSize(numbersArray, index + 1, num,reducedNum - k, maxNum);
    }
}
void findCombinations(int number, int maxSubset){
    int arrayNumbers[number];
    findCombinationGivenSize(arrayNumbers, 0, number, number, maxSubset);
}

int main(){
    int number = 7;
    int maxPartitions = 3;
    findCombinations(number, maxPartitions);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And, of course, you can add on your main the conditions for `number` and `maxPartitions`.